# How to extract closed-captioning from streaming online video

Tags: video, streaming, closed-captions, srt

I found this, but it seems to be about streaming videos that have been downloaded. Is there any way to extract the SRT from streaming videos without downloading them?  Or is there any way to download a streaming video from, say, cbs.com or HULU or iTunes (not Youtube) with the SRT file intact (assuming they use SRT)? Please bear in mind that I'm not really a programmer. I just know HTML and a few other minor things.  Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877610/how-can-i-extract-captions-subtitles-from-this-streaming-video

More info--
I run this site: tvmeg.com and for years we've had transcripts from the daytime soaps (and a few primetime shows). I used an ATI card on a desktop that grabs the closed-captioning from the TV or video. However, it's very old technology that they no longer make and it won't work on online videos. I just learned about SRT, which is great, but I haven't found any already made for daytime soaps, only primetime shows. I'm going to be moving soon and need to be able to find an alternate way to get the CC from the soaps since I won't have cable in my new place for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer from another page will work for you. I had to fight like hell to get this to work, and I think it only worked in Firefox, but I could be wrong. I "think" the key here is to launch your developer tools before your video starts to load, otherwise the request for the .srt subtitle file will have already processed before the dev-tools started logging the network requests & responses.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877610/how-can-i-extract-captions-subtitles-from-this-streaming-video